# installing maven with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to install Maven integration plugin in Eclipse Helios. But I am getting error like

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.1.20140328-1905 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.1.20140328-1905)
  Missing requirement: async-http-client 1.6.5.20140328-1501 (com.ning.async-http-client 1.6.5.20140328-1501) requires 'package org.slf4j 1.6.2' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.1.20140328-1905 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.1.20140328-1905)
    To: com.ning.async-http-client [1.6.5.20140328-1501]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solve my problem. May be this will be helpful for some of you guys

add this link to your eclipse and it will work.

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3

Comment: It worked after I changed the URL to the m2eclipse update site to "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3". Thanks!